# Is it Possible to automate a dependency mapping report from TFS or VisualStudio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell

I'm having some trouble finding an answer or method to somehow generate a dependency mapping report between all of our TFS projects (apps & assemblies) at my company.

We currently have a spreadsheet that needs to be continuously updated manually. This reference is important because if we want to clean up old unused projects in bulk we need a reliable source of all of our dependencies between assemblies and applications to make sure that we don't kill an assembly that is currently being referenced by another assembly or app.

I keep feeling like this may be something that can be accomplished with Powershell somehow, whenever I think of something that is so tedious and time consuming my mind always goes to: "Powershell can do it faster!"

I'm not 100% sure if this is the right forum but any help getting pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method in MSDN: [Map dependencies across your solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx) However there are also many limitations.

> When you want to understand dependencies across your code, visualize
>   them by creating code maps. This helps you see how the code fits
>   together without reading through files and lines of code.

[image]